# PaaS/hosted PaaS without restrictions

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services, openshift, appfog, paas

I'm looking for nice PaaS that could run applicatons which:

1. Listens to non-80 external port (25th, its a SMTP server)
2. Writes to the persisting filesystem

(its 2 different applications, so PaaS I'm looking for dont have to have both features)

I tried different PaaS and IaaS:

- Heroku: no/no
- OpenShift: no/yes
- AppFog: apparently no/no
- AWS: yes/yes - but its IaaS

I understand, that listening to 25th port is not really popular feature, so I'm open to host some PaaS without strict restrictions on say AWS. Is there is such?

Comment: May I ask why you want a PaaS? PaaS is more of an *application* runtime rather than a hosting service or IaaS, which sounds more like what you actually need. That said no PaaS will not give you (1) just by the definition of it, and the (2) is a bad practice when it comes to web-applications.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think OpenShift is going to give you exactly what you are looking for however as you have denoted you will have persistent storage.

As you have denoted port 25 is not one of the external ports that your application can [bind to with OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1038-i-cant-bind-to-a-port). The reason for this is because in too many situation the use of port 25 leads to accounts not complying with the [Acceptable Use Policy](https://www.openshift.com/legal/acceptable_use).

However there are mail alternatives for SMTP such as the use of [mailgun](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/email-in-the-cloud-with-mailgun), this service works over port 80 and service as an SMTP service.

In this way OpenShif can meet both of your requirements (kinda).

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to hosting the PaaS yourself, you can try out [Cloudify](http://www.cloudifysource.org). It's open-source, and your application not limited in what it can do on your instance.

Disclaimer: I work for [Gigaspaces](http://www.gigaspaces.com), which develops Cloudify,

Answer (score 0):

You may check out http://paasify.it. It's a comparative list of current PaaS vendors that I have compiled.

As for persistent storage select 'Filesystem' under Services. Possible PaaS include [Clever Cloud](http://www.clever-cloud.com/), [HP Cloud Application Platform as a Service](https://www.hpcloud.com/products/PaaSApp), [Stackato](http://www.activestate.com/stackato) and [Static](http://static.com/).

I'm not aware which do allow listening on port 25. I suggest using a addon service (e.g. mailgun), like SFERICH suggested.

Cheers Stefan

Answer (score 0):

I just got into the following article and your question. I hope it can solve your demand for flexibility: 
[Dokku on Digital Ocean](https://www.andrewmunsell.com/blog/dokku-tutorial-digital-ocean)